# How to split two first names that together in two different words in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, nlp, data-cleaning

I am trying to split misspelled first names. Most of them are joined together. I was wondering if there is any way to separate two first names that are together into two different words.

For example, if the misspelled name is `trujillohernandez` then to be separated to `trujillo hernandez`.

I am trying to create a *function* that can do this for a whole column with thousands of misspelled names like the example above. However, I haven't been successful. Spell-checkers libraries do not work given that these are first names and they are Hispanic names.

I would be really grateful if you can help to develop some sort of function to make it happen.

Comment: Unless you have a list of all the possible first names, there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above not having a list of possible names will cause a problem.  However, and perhaps not perfect, but to offer something try...

Given a dataframe example like...

```
    Name
0   sofíagomez
1   isabelladelgado
2   luisvazquez
3   juanhernandez
4   valentinatrujillo
5   camilagutierrez
6   joséramos
7   carlossantana
```

**Code (Python):**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# longest list of hispanic surnames I could find in a table
url = r'https://namecensus.com/data/hispanic.html'

# download the table into a frame and clean up the header
page = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(page.text.replace('<br />',' '))
df = table[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

# move the frame of surnames to a list
last_names = df['Last name / Surname'].tolist()
last_names = [each_string.lower() for each_string in last_names]

# create a test dataframe of joined firstnames and lastnames
data = {'Name' : ['sofíagomez', 'isabelladelgado', 'luisvazquez', 'juanhernandez', 'valentinatrujillo', 'camilagutierrez', 'joséramos', 'carlossantana']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])

# create new columns for the matched names
lastname = '({})'.format('|'.join(last_names))
df['Firstname'] = df.Name.str.replace(str(lastname)+'$', '', regex=True).fillna('--not found--')
df['Lastname'] = df.Name.str.extract(str(lastname)+'$', expand=False).fillna('--not found--')

# output the dataframe
print('\n\n')
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    Name                Firstname   Lastname
0   sofíagomez          sofía       gomez
1   isabelladelgado     isabella    delgado
2   luisvazquez         luis        vazquez
3   juanhernandez       juan        hernandez
4   valentinatrujillo   valentina   trujillo
5   camilagutierrez     camila      gutierrez
6   joséramos           josé        ramos
7   carlossantana       carlos      santana
```

Further cleanup may be required but perhaps it gets the majority of names split.

Comment: @bernard romero does this help?